# Write binary data using javascript on the server

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

I'm trying to output a PDF using server side javascript (ASP). The current method I'm using is:

```
xfile=Server.MapPath(lib.fso.GetTempName())
xf=lib.fopen(xfile,"wb");
lib.fwrite(xf,this.buffer);
lib.fclose(xf);
outB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
outB.Type = 1
outB.Open()
outB.LoadFromFile (xfile)
Response.BinaryWrite(outB.Read())
outB.Close()
lib.fso.DeleteFile(xfile);
```

This works, but requires write access on the server. Is there a way to do the same thing without writing to a file?

I havn't been able to figure out how to convert the string  `this.buffer` into a `array of byte` that I can then write using `Response.BinaryWrite` without writing to a file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use VBScript.

replace the above code with:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(StringToMultiByte(this.buffer));
```

and add this to the end of the file:

```
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">

function StringToMultiByte(S)
   Dim i, MultiByte
   For i=1 To Len(S)
   MultiByte = MultiByte & ChrB(Asc(Mid(S,i,1)))
   Next
   StringToMultiByte = MultiByte
End function

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use:-

```
Response.Write(this.buffer)
```

Assuming the codepage of the response is set correctly (I.e., its the same as in the Locale that the VBScript is running in) then Response.Write should do the same conversion that your StringToMultiByte is doing.

I suspect you've tried this and is hasn't worked.  If so I really think you need to look into why that is rather attempt this strange usage of BinaryWrite.  Currently your solution is going to kill your server.

Comment: Could you be more clear on "going to kill your server"?
I did try the Response.write method, but it created corrupt PDFs. I suspect this is due to how the images are encoded and output as text. I'd bet that Response.write does some sort of encoding which is corrupting the image data as it is written to the output buffer.